# Recommendations for open source ESB & BPM tools

Tags: open-source, esb, business-process-management

Can anyone recommend an open source ESB tool/runtime which is extensible to include or compatible with BPM (either BPEL or exec BPMN)?

Ideally I'm looking for something with proven scalability, and a good set of graphical support/maintenance interfaces.

I'm aware of a couple of things which do this in the commercial world but a but not too familiar with o/s offerings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend WSO2 ESB. It is based on the Carbon platform which offers a wide range of OSGi based components. BPM is one of the features available in the platform and can be installed onto the ESB. BPM is available as a separate product as well, but if you simply need an ESB which has BPM capabilities, you can simply install the BPM feature onto the ESB

It has a fully-fledged management console & Eclipse based tooling.

See

1. WSO2 ESB http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/
2. WSO2 BPS http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server/
3. Eclipse based development studio http://wso2.com/products/carbon-studio/
4. Repository containing extensible features http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.2.0/

Comment: many thanks i'll have a look into it.

Comment: You should really disclose the fact that you work for WSO2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that in the open source community sometimes you will find very good projects that allow you to build the UIs using the technology that you want. Providing you flexibility to adapt them to legacy applications. jBPM5 provides you more than a BPM System, it is integrated with a Rule Engine and Complex Event Processing features, you can find more information about it here: http://www.jbpm.org

Because it's open source you can also plug it in with any ESB out there, proprietary or open source.
Hope it helps!
Cheers

Comment: its more the case that we'd be looking to buy some existing ui rather than build and test it. Time to market won't allow much else. i'll be checking out jbpm though.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.com/mule-esb-open-source-esb) and [Apache Servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/home.html) can offer these things.  However, Servicemix does not have the nice graphical management UI you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

big pain is in deciding the correct tool! me too looking for some best BPM tool to explore, have tried Apache ServiceMix but Mule seems to be a better option.

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer! Leave a comment next time.